# combining date & time into one datetime field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

i am trying to save and convert the date and time fields from a form into a singular datetime attribute. at present i am passing the date and time as per below

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4vsUi3DN9ucsxkrojPMe/J4tvJwsIebvGzv0gC0/w8g=", "event"=>{"team_id"=>"4", "date"=>"Monday, July 01, 2013", "time"=>"06:15 am", "event"=>"1", "location_name"=>"Another Loc", "duration"=>"10", "arrival_time"=>"10", "opponent_name"=>"Test", "home_or_away"=>"Home"}, "commit"=>"Create Event"}
```

and attempting to save this data with the following

```
params[:event][:datetime] = DateTime.parse(params[:event][:date]+params[:event][:time])
    @event = Event.new(params[:event])
```

which seems to be saving the data correctly, though when i attempt to display it with the following i am getting a time that is 10 hours in the future

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:event_time] = '%l:%M %p'
```

Comment: because of additional "10"?

Comment: where is there an additional 10?

Comment: its like rails is apply the timezone to the time directly stored in the database though i dont wish for it do so

Comment: can't u set that timezone as your wish? don't know nething abt rails :)

Answer (score -1):

```
time_to_merge = Time.new
date_to_merge = Date.today
merged_datetime = DateTime.new(date_to_merge.year, date_to_merge.month,
                               date_to_merge.day, time_to_merge.hour,
                               time_to_merge.min, time_to_merge.sec)
```